# Criar efeito de fontawesone piscando

Tags: css

Tenho um software que uma parte é um chat interno, quero colocar o efeito de font piscando quando uma nova mensagem chegar.

```
<i class="fa fa-comments"></i>
```

Ao lado do nome eu tenho a imagem da fontawsome acima, e quando chegar a mensagem quero que a font pisque.

Comment: Piscando como? "Sumindo e Aparecendo" ou "Alternando de Cor"?

Comment: https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/

Tututi, tututu :P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Para criar um efeito piscante em um ícone do Font Awesome usando CSS, você pode utilizar a propriedade *animation*. Aqui está um exemplo de como criar esse efeito para um ícone de envelope:

Uma opção é usar `opacity` indo de `0` a `1`, e aplicar uma animação. Veja um exemplo:

```css
@keyframes fa-blink {
     0% { opacity: 1; }
     50% { opacity: 0.5; }
     100% { opacity: 0; }
 }
.fa-blink {
   -webkit-animation: fa-blink .75s linear infinite;
   -moz-animation: fa-blink .75s linear infinite;
   -ms-animation: fa-blink .75s linear infinite;
   -o-animation: fa-blink .75s linear infinite;
   animation: fa-blink .75s linear infinite;
}
```

```html
<img class="fa-blink" src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-image-128.png"/>
```

Para usar basta inserir a classe `fa-blink` no seu `<i>`. Veja:

```
 <i class="fa fa-comments fa-blink"></i>
```

Comment: Do modo que está ai não precisa de `50% { opacity: 0.5; }`, ele já vai ser isso por interpolação

Answer (score 3):

Vc pode criar uma animação associada ao FontAwesome, tipo a class `.fa.pisca`. Assim sempre que vc usar o FontAwesome basta vc acrescentar a classe `pisca` onde vc quer piscando. `<i class="fa ... pisca"></i>`

Veja o exemplo

```css
.fa.pisca {
    font-size: 30px;
    color: red;
    opacity: 0;
    animation: anima 1s ease infinite;
}
@keyframes anima {
    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<i class="fa fa-comments pisca"></i> pisca
```

---

Exemplo com animação apenas no `:hover`

```css
.fa.pisca {
    font-size: 30px;
    color: red;
    opacity: 1;
}
@keyframes anima {
    to {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
ul {
    list-style: none;
}
li {
    cursor: pointer;
}
li:hover .pisca {
    animation: anima 750ms ease infinite;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<ul>
    <li><i class="fa fa-comments pisca"></i> pisca</li>
</ul>
```